# Como validar el orden que las imagenes son seleccionadas

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Es difícil encontrar un titulo que detalle. paso a explicar.

Tengo un formulario donde ingreso hasta 5 imagenes. Pero solo la primera la requiere si o si (como imagen principal del articulo). Las otras 4 son opcional. Estas imagenes se ingresan con inputs

Lo que necesito hacer es que por php o por validaciones del request, preferiría este ultimo, no me permita ingresar una ingresar una imagen de cualquier input, sino que conserve el orden, primero el input de la imagen principal, luego el segundo que ya es opcional y asi hasta el ultimo si se quiere

```
@section('contenido')
{!!     Form::open(['route'=>'articulos.store','method'=>'POST','files'=>true]) !!}

    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('imagen_1','Imagen Principal:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('imagen_1') !!}
        <br>
        {!! Form::text('descripcion_1',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Descripcion de la foto...']) !!}

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('imagen_2','Imagen 2:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('imagen_2') !!}
        <br>
        {!! Form::text('descripcion_2',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Descripcion de la foto...']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('imagen_3','Imagen 3:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('imagen_3') !!}
        <br>
        {!! Form::text('descripcion_3',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Descripcion de la foto...']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('imagen_4','Imagen 4:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('imagen_4') !!}
        <br>
        {!! Form::text('descripcion_4',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Descripcion de la foto...']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('imagen_5','Imagen 5:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('imagen_5') !!}
        <br>
        {!! Form::text('descripcion_5',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Descripcion de la foto...']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Agregar articulo',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de entender lo del orden,  ¿quieres decir que no se pueda subir la imagen 3 si no hay nada en la 2? Por ejemplo

Comment: exacto. si no selecciono una imagen en el input anterior, que no pueda agregar una foto ese input o algo asi. la solucion dinamica de agregar inputs no me esta andando

Comment: Lo ideal sería validar en back-end con Laravel, no en front-end como lo propone sioesi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma Laravel de hacerlo es utilizar las validaciones para dichos campos, una combinación de varias validaciones de `required*`.

No lo puedo probar en este momento, pero yo utilizaría la validación `required` para el primer campo y `required_with` o `required_if` para las 
siguientes imágenes:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'imagen_1' => 'required',
        'imagen_2' => 'required_with:imagen_3',
        'imagen_3' => 'required_with:imagen_4',
        'imagen_4' => 'required_with:imagen_5',
    ];
}
```

Comment: genial. no entendia muy bien la diferencia entre _with e _if. Y justo en la documentacion esos 2 no estan ejempleficados. Es justo lo que buscaba hacer